# SQL update trigger to when system time is > 20 minutes of column time

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am very new to SQL Triggers.

I have a column "Status_ID" where it gets updated by different values. My Trigger should flag a column "Alarm_Late_Pickup" whenever the "Status_ID" is not updated to value "4" before 20 minutes of the current time, the next step is to flag another column "Late_Pickup" when the "Status_ID" is not set to "5" when the current time is Larger then the "Pickup_Time" column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that you need an event schedule rather than a trigger.  But, in SQL Server, you can do what you want with a computed column or view:

```
ALTER TABLE 
    t
ADD 
    IsFinished AS (CASE 
                        WHEN 
                            (Pickup_Time < DATEADD(MINUTE, -20, GETDATE()) 
                            OR
                            (Delivery_Time < DATEADD(MINUTE, -20, GETDATE()))) THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 END)
```

This adds a column to the table that is recalculated each time it is used.

Comment: The script you mentioned was very helpful which I will use in another scenario. Now I think it was my mistake to mention the exact requirement. I have a column "Status_ID" where it gets updated by different values. My Trigger should flag a column "Alarm_Late_Pickup" whenever the "Status_ID" is not updated to value "4" before 20 minutes of the current time, the next step is to flag another column "Late_Pickup" when the "Status_ID" is not set to "5" and so on. the solution you provided is keep changing as when I modified it to be "Package_Status" related.

Comment: alter table tbl_dispatching
    add Late_Piackup_Alaram as (case when (Pickup_Time_from < dateadd(minute, -15, CAST(GETDATE() AS time(7)))
  and (status_id < '4') and (Pickup_Date = CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
                       ) then 1 else 0 end)

alter table tbl_dispatching
    add Late_Piackup as (case when (Pickup_Time_To < CAST(GETDATE() AS time(7))
  and (status_id < '5') and (Pickup_Date = CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
                       ) then 1 else 0 end)

Comment: I have posted the script which I modified , the problem is when the status_id is changed from 4 to 5 (as part of the work process of my application), the Late_Pickup_Alarm is set to 0 again.

Comment: @MohammadAbbas . . . If you have another question, you should ask it as *another*  question.  I think this one is pretty clear.